# Mapbox map not centered after doing click on it

Tags: vuejs2, mapbox-gl-js

The problem is that after clicking the map, the center of the map is not the clicked location, instead is the bottom right corner. As you can see in the code, I am using the click event. This event returns the lnglat property, which should be the lat and long of the clicked location. After that, I just pass this as a parameter to the setCenter function.
I don't know why, but it isn't working as expected.

```js
<template>
  <q-page id="map" class="row items-center justify-evenly"></q-page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'PageIndex',
  data() {
    return {
      accessToken:
        'pk.eyJ1IjoidHJldmUiLCJhIjoiY2tieHpzcXMwMHQycDJvb3l5Mmx1dDNtaiJ9.zwt0OXOxbSe7qdQqZkktHw',
      mapStyle: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      coordinates: [-82.43212635515275, 23.12598291578537]
    };
  },
  components: {},
  methods: {
    createMap() {
      mapboxgl.accessToken = this.accessToken;
      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: this.mapStyle, // stylesheet location
        center: [-82.4282686540247, 23.122116998741006], // starting position [lng, lat]
        zoom: 15 // starting zoom
      });
      map.on('click', function(e) {
        console.log('Map clicked:', e);
        map.setCenter(e.lngLat);
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.createMap();
  }
});
</script>

<style scoped>
#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Code looks ok. Put it on a codepen so we can see it in action?

Comment: Thanks @SteveBennett, I already solved it creating a div element inside the q-page element and adding the map to this child element. Thanks anyway!!!